# Change DataTable Column Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have one DataTable like this:

```
Attribute          Percentage      ReferenceAmount        TaxAmount
------------       ------------     ----------------      -----------
  Sales              5.00             5000                  250
  VAT                2.00             250                   5
  Discount            0                 0                   100
```

I want to Bind this DataTable with one GridView.
But in the GridView, I dont want to display 0. Instead of Zero, I just want leave that cell as empty. I dont want to display any other thing if that contains Zero.
How to replace EmptyString instead of Zero in the DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following GridView DataBound method will loop through every cell in the GridView and replace "0" with an empty string:

```
        protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[i].Text == "0")
                    {
                        row.Cells[i].Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am answering the question late, I know the answer is already accepted. But in the accepted answer, you are iterating the rows after databinding and then setting the value.

It would be better to replace the value at DataBinding time. It will over come the extra overhead of the iteration of the gridview rows.

You can use the `RowDataBound` event of the GridView. Here is the complete code..

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    System.Data.DataRow dr = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

    if (dr["Percentage"].ToString() == "0")
    {
        ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPercentage")).Text = "";
        //this is template field
        //OR---If you don't use template field you  can do like..--
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text  = "";
    }      
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could easily add an property called PercentageDescription as String

```
 public string PercentageDescription
 {
    return Percentage == 0 ? " " : Percentage.ToString();
 }
```