# Decode html from a cell in datarows in custom webpart

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have the following code to load data from a list in sharepoint website to a custom web part.

```
 private void Data_load()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            string currentName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='Person or Group'>" + currentName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spdev-6/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList lists = web.GetList("Lists/Advertisements");

                    SPListItemCollection items = lists.GetItems(query);

                    if (items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //foreach(SPListItem item in items)
                        //{
                        //  string decodeDescrip = Server.HtmlDecode( item["Details"].ToString());
                        //  item["Details"] = decodeDescrip;

                        //}
                        dt = items.GetDataTable();


                    }
                    else
                        lbldata.Text = "No data to show";



                    GridViewD.DataSource = dt;
                    GridViewD.DataBind();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Advertisement"] = dt;


                }
            }

        }
```

Now the issue is  i am getting Htmlencode data in  one of the columns. Now i have to remove it from grid view. So how it can be removed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the Column in the DataTable before assigning it to the Grid. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717369/change-datatable-column-value) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tat996zc.aspx).

```
    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[i].Text == "0")
                {
                    row.Cells[i].Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You could also change the value on DataBinding as described in [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717369/change-datatable-column-value?lq=1).

```
    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[i].Text == "0")
                {
                    row.Cells[i].Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```